# Problem evaluating an anticommutator in supersymmetric quantum mechanical gauge theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, supersymmetry

I am trying to reproduce the results of a certain paper [here](https://inspirehep.net/literature/201322). In particular, I'm trying to verify their eqn 5.31.

The setup is N = 4 gauge quantum mechanics, obtained by the dimensional reduction of N = 1 gauge theory in 4 dimensions. $\sigma^i$ denotes the ith pauli matrix. $\lambda_{A \alpha}$ is a two component complex fermion (or rather its $\alpha$th component). $A$ labels the generators of the gauge group.

\begin{align*}
    H &= \frac{1}{2}\pi^m_A \pi^m_A + \frac{1}{4} g^2 (f_{ABC}\phi^m_B \phi^n_C)^2 + igf_{ABC}\bar{\lambda}_A \sigma^m\phi^m_B \lambda_C \\
    Q_{\alpha} &= (\sigma^m \lambda_A)_{\alpha}(\pi^m_A - iW^m_A)\\
    \bar{Q}_{\beta} &= (\bar{\lambda}_B\sigma^n)_{\beta}(\pi^n_B + iW^n_B)\\
    W&= \frac{1}{6}g f_{ABC} \epsilon_{mnp}\phi^m_A \phi^n_B \phi^p_C \\
    W^m_A &= \frac{\partial W}{\partial \phi^m_A} \\
    [\phi^m_A, \pi^n_B] &= i \delta_{AB}\delta^{mn} \\
    \{\lambda_{A \alpha}, \bar{\lambda}_{B \beta} \} &= \delta_{AB} \delta_{\alpha \beta}\\
    G_A &= f_{ABC}(\phi^m_B\pi^m_C - i\bar{\lambda}_B \lambda_C).
\end{align*}

It is claimed that

\begin{align*}
    \{Q_{\alpha}, \bar{Q}_{\beta}\} &= 2 \delta_{\alpha \beta}H - 2g(\sigma^m)_{\alpha \beta} \phi^m_A G_A
\end{align*}

This can also be written as

\begin{align}
    \{Q_{\alpha}, \bar{Q}_{\beta}\} &= \delta_{\alpha \beta}(\pi^m_A \pi^m_A + \frac{1}{2} g^2 (f_{ABC}\phi^m_B \phi^n_C)^2 + i2gf_{ABC}\bar{\lambda}_A \sigma^m\phi^m_B \lambda_C) - 2g(\sigma^m)_{\alpha \beta} \phi^m_A f_{ABC}(\phi^m_B\pi^m_C - i\bar{\lambda}_B \lambda_C).
\end{align}

I have spent many hours trying to confirm this, but unable so far to do so.

\begin{align*}
    \{Q_{\alpha}, \bar{Q}_{\beta}\} &= \{(\sigma^m \lambda_A)_{\alpha}(\pi^m_A - iW^m_A) (\bar{\lambda}_B\sigma^n )_{\beta}(\pi^n_B + iW^n_B)\}\\
    &=(\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\lambda_{A \theta})( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})[\pi^m_A \pi^n_B + W^{n m}_{BA} + iW^n_B\pi^m_A - i W^m_A \pi^n_B + W^m_A W^n_B] \\
    &+( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})(\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\lambda_{A \theta})[\pi^n_B \pi^m_A - W^{m n}_{AB} - iW^m_A \pi^n_B + iW^n_B \pi^m_A + W^n_B W^m_A] \\
    &= (\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})(\lambda_{A \theta} \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}) [\pi^m_A \pi^n_B + W^{n m}_{BA} + iW^n_B\pi^m_A - i W^m_A \pi^n_B + W^m_A W^n_B] \\
    &+ (\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\lambda_{A \theta})[\pi^n_B \pi^m_A - W^{m n}_{AB} - iW^m_A \pi^n_B + iW^n_B \pi^m_A + W^n_B W^m_A] \\
    &= (\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\theta \beta})[\pi^m_A \pi^n_A + iW^n_A\pi^m_A - i W^m_A \pi^n_A + W^m_A W^n_A] \\
    &+ (\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})[( \lambda_{A \theta}\bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma})-( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\lambda_{A \theta})]W^{m n}_{AB}\\
    &= (\delta_{mn} \delta_{\alpha \beta} + i \epsilon_{mnp}\sigma^p_{\alpha \beta})[\pi^m_A \pi^n_A + iW^n_A\pi^m_A - i W^m_A \pi^n_A + W^m_A W^n_A] \\
    &- 2(\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\lambda_{A \theta})W^{m n}_{AB}\\
    &= \delta_{\alpha \beta}(\pi^m_A \pi^m_A + W^m_AW^m_A) + 2\epsilon_{mnp}\sigma^p_{\alpha \beta} W^m_A \pi^n_A - 2(\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\lambda_{A \theta})W^{m n}_{AB}\\
    &=\delta_{\alpha \beta}(\pi^m_A \pi^m_A + \frac{1}{2} g^2 (f_{ABC}\phi^m_B \phi^n_C)^2) +g \epsilon _{mrs}f_{ABC}\phi^r_B \phi^s_C\epsilon_{mnp}\sigma^p_{\alpha \beta} W^m_A \pi^n_A - 2(\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\lambda_{A \theta})W^{m n}_{AB}\\
    &= \delta_{\alpha \beta}(\pi^m_A \pi^m_A + \frac{1}{2} g^2 (f_{ABC}\phi^m_B \phi^n_C)^2) - 2g(\sigma^m)_{\alpha \beta} \phi^m_A f_{ABC}\phi^m_B\pi^m_C - 2(\sigma^m_{\alpha \theta}\sigma^n_{\gamma \beta})( \bar{\lambda}_{B \gamma}\lambda_{A \theta})g \epsilon_{mnp}f_{ABC}\phi^p_C.
\end{align*}

The first three terms are correct. But the fourth term is wrong (it should instead be two different terms above). I have spent many hours on this. I think I must have some conceptual misunderstanding about these sorts of calculations, because I can't do it. I am hoping someone can help me out and clarify what I'm doing wrong please.